# Traversing a Binary Tree to Get The Splitting Conditions - ctree(party), recursive function

Tags: r, binary-tree, party

I am trying to reproduce the error which I get with my dataset using a general dataset. Please correct me if I am missing something.

After fitting a `Classification` tree using `library(party)`, I am trying to get the split conditions of the tree on each node. I managed to write a code, which i believed was working fine, until I found a bug. Could anyone help me to solve it?

My code:

```
 require(party)
 iris$Petal.Width <- as.factor(iris$Petal.Width)#imp to convert to factorial
 (ct <- ctree(Species ~ ., data = iris))
 plot(ct)
 #print(ct)
  a <- ct #convert it to s4 object
  t <- a@tree

 #recursive function to traverse the tree and get the splitting conditions

 recurse_tree <- function(tree,ret_list=list(),sub_list=list()){
   if(!tree$terminal){
     sub_list$assign <-list(tree$psplit$splitpoint,tree$psplit$variableName,class(tree$psplit))
     names(sub_list)[which(names(sub_list)=="assign")] <- paste("node",tree$nodeID,sep="")
     ret_list <- recurse_tree(tree$left, ret_list, sub_list)
     ret_list <- recurse_tree(tree$right, ret_list, sub_list)

  }
  if(tree$terminal){
    ret_list$assign <- c(sub_list, tree$prediction)
    names(ret_list)[which(names(ret_list)=="assign")] <- paste("node",tree$nodeID,sep="")
    return(ret_list)
   }
   return(ret_list)
  }

  result <- recurse_tree(t) #call to the functions
```

Now, the result gives me the list of of all nodes and split conditions and predictions (I assumed). But, when I check the split conditions for

- expected output on **Node5**: {1.1, 1.2, 1.6, 1.7 } `# from printing the tree print(ct), I get this`
- output I get on **Node5 from my function**: {"1" , "1.3" ,"1.4" ,"1.5" } which is basically the split condition of Node6, which is wrong. How did I get this?

  `z <- result[2] #I know node5 is second in the list`

  ```
  z <- unlist(z,recursive = F,use.names = T) #unlist
  levels(z[[3]][[1]]) [which((z[[3]][[1]])==0)] #to find levels of corresponding values
  ```

[image: plot for more details]

What I doubt, my function(`recurse_tree`) is always giving me the split conditions of the right terminal node and not left node. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is it your intention to reassign to `ret_list<-` twice in the not-terminal branch? That doesn't seem correct; you onlt return the last one essentially It would be helpful to more clearly describe the exactly output you are after. There may be better ways to extract it.

Comment: @MrFlick thanks for your response. My intension is to get all, the splitting conditions for a Terminal node. Expected output on **Node5** : {1.1, 1.2, 1.6, 1.7 } , from my function. As well as output on **Node6** should be: {1, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5}. But my function returns me wrong output on **Node5**. I know I am doing something wrong in my function while calling it recursively and assigning to `ret_list`. But I am not getting it right.

Comment: I would recommend that you considert the new recommended implementation of `ctree()` in package `partykit`. The underlying design of the tree structure is much simpler and better documented - for a starting point see `vignette("partykit", package = "partykit")`. For example, this has a dedicated class to represent a `partysplit` or you can turn a recursive `partynode` into a list etc.